# How to calculate line integral over an ellipse with vector field undefined inside the ellipse?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

> Given vector fields:
>   $$
> P=\frac{-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\\
> Q=\frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2+y^2}
> $$
>   calculate $\oint_CP\,dx+Q\,dy$ over ellipse $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{36}=1$.
>
> Define the domain where the function $U=\arctan\big(\frac{y}{x-1}\big)$ is the potential function to the given field.

I tried doing parametrization for the curve that can de derived from ellipse:
$$
c(t)=\langle 5\cos t,6\sin t\rangle
$$
and plugging this directly into the integral. But very quickly the integral becomes quite complicated.

I think there must be some trick here which I don't see. If there's a potential function then the field is conservative. But the problem is that the field is not defined at point $(1,0)$ which is inside the ellipse. For the same reason I don't think we can use Green's theorem as well.

Comment: Do you know Green's theorem?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, now that you mentioned it I actually did calculate $P_y$ and $Q_x$ and it turns out that $\iint (P_y-Q_x)=0$ so the integral is zero I guess? (because $P_y=Q_x$)

Comment: You tell me! When you're done, write it up as an answer and accept it, which'll close out the question (but won't get you any points).

Comment: I'm not interested in points :)  I will write this as edit to the question but there's one part of the answer which is missing: the domain for the potential function. The way I see the potential is undefined along the line $x=1$, is it correct?

Comment: I hadn't really looked at the formulas for $P$ and $Q$; these are not even defined at the points on the ellipse where $x = 1$, so I'm not certain what the integral even means.

Comment: @John Hughes: of course the components *are* defined at the points *on the ellipse* where $x=1$, for in those cases $y\neq0$. The singularity happens when the denominators vanish, which happens at the point $(1,0)$.

Comment: D'oh! Nevermind.... Need more coffee. :)

Comment: @symplectomorphic so the field has the potential function everywhere on the $xy$ plane except for $(1,0)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E$ denote the interior of the ellipse and $\partial E$ the boundary (i.e. the ellipse itself). You're trying to calculate

$$\color{blue}{\oint_{\partial E}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}}$$

Your first hope is that Green's theorem applies, so you can instead calculate

$$\int_E(Q_x-P_y)\,dA$$

The problem is that *the hypotheses of Green's theorem are not satisfied*, for the functions $P$ and $Q$ are not continuously differentiable throughout the region $E$. As you observed, there is no way we may continuously extend the field to be defined at the point $(1,0)$, so that point is a singularity.

The way to proceed in such cases is to put a little closed curve around the singularity but still lying entirely inside the region $E$ of interest; in this case a unit circle will be convenient (the calculation will show you why). So let $D$ be the unit disk centered at $(1,0)$, and let $\partial D$ be the unit *circle* centered there, which has parametrization $C(t)=(\cos t +1, \sin t)$ for $t\in[0,2\pi)$.

You can easily check by direct calculation that

$$\color{red}{\oint_{\partial D}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}}=\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)\,dt=2\pi$$

Now, consider the region $E-D$, the complement of the disk in the elliptical region. In *this* region, $P$ and $Q$ *are* continuously differentiable everywhere, so we *may* use Green's theorem, which says

$$\int_{E-D}(Q_x-P_y)\,dA=\oint_{\partial(E-D)}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}\tag{$\star$}$$

The left side vanishes, because $Q_x-P_y=0$ in the region $E-D$. What about the right side? What is the "boundary" $\partial(E-D)$ of the elliptical annular region $E-D$? It is $\partial E - \partial D$, where we interpret the negative sign on $\partial D$ to mean reversing the standard counterclockwise orientation.

So $(\star)$ says

$$0=\color{blue}{\oint_{\partial E}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}}-\color{red}{\oint_{\partial D}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{R}}$$

The blue integral is the one the problem asks for, and the red integral we calculated above.

---

To summarize, the strategy for calculating line integrals of *curl-free* fields around closed curves that encircle a single singularity is to replace the original closed curve with an easier one (but still contained within the original one). Green's theorem in the region *between* the curves guarantees the line integral around the easier curve equals the line integral around the original curve.

What makes a good candidate for an "easier curve"? Well, you're trying to find a curve whose parametrization will make the integrand simple enough to calculate. In your problem, integrating around the *ellipse* gives a "hard" integrand. But integrating around a *circle centered at the singularity* gives an "easy" integrand.

Why a circle in this case? Because your field is closely related to the pullback of the length element of a circle of radius $r$ (the length element is $ds=r d\theta$); thus it was, in some sense, *tailor-made* to be integrated around a circle. It is not always so easy to spot what sort of curve will make the line integral easier, but you should remember the general form $(-\frac{y}{r^2}, \frac{x}{r^2})$, which is $\frac{1}{r}$ times the circle's unit tangent vector. The line integral of the unit tangent vector around the circle gives $2\pi r$, and the factor $\frac{1}{r}$ scales the result to $2\pi$. (In other words, you are just integrating $d\theta=\frac{1}{r}ds$ around the circle.) So the *radius* of the circle you use around the singularity doesn't matter. (This make sense, because the region between two concentric circles centered at the singularity doesn't contain a singularity and the field is conservative there, so by the above argument, the line integral of the field around them should be the same.)

Comment: PS: The deeper moral of this problem is that *the line integrals of two closed curves in the plane, one inside the other, will be equal whenever the (two-dimensional) curl of the field vanishes in the region between them* (and there are no singularities there). This has to do with the "homotopy-invariance" of the integrals of closed 1-forms.

Comment: First of all this is an amazing answer! I have a few questions though: did you just plug in the parametric curve values into $\int_{\partial D} F\cdot dr$? I got $\cos^2 t+\sin^2t$ in the nominator but in the denominator: $$x^2-2x+1+y^2=(\cos t+1)^2-2(\cos t+1)+1+\sin^2 t=0$$

Comment: @Yos: if $x=1+\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$, then $P=-\frac{\sin t}{(1+\cos t - 1)^2+\sin^2t}=-\frac{\sin t}{1}=-\sin t$, and $dx=-\sin t\,dt$, hence $P\,dx=\sin^2t\,dt$, etc.

Comment: (You seem to have forgotten that $x=\color{red}{1+}\cos t$, not $\cos t$ alone.)

Comment: You're absolutely right, forgot that $x=1+\cos t$. My other question is you chose the circle around singularity to be of radius one hence we got $2\pi$. but what if you chose another circle which would be much tighter, say with radius $0.5$ then we'd get a different value when calculating $\int_{\partial D} F\cdot dr$. but the answer must be unique right?

Comment: @Yos: no, you wouldn't get a different answer if you chose a circle of radius $0.5$. This follows from my first comment on my answer: because $Q_x-P_y$ vanishes in the region between the two concentric circles and because there are no singularities in that annulus, the line integral around one circle will equal the line integral around the other circle. In other words, the exact same reasoning given in my answer shows that the radius of the circle doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm trying to understand: if we chose a circle of radius $0.2$ then $\int_{\partial D}Fdr=0.04\cdot 2\pi$. Then $\int_{\partial E} Fdr=\int_{\partial D}Fdr=0.04\cdot 2\pi\neq 2\pi$

Comment: @Yos: **no**, integrating $F$ around a circle of radius $0.04$ does not give $0.04\cdot 2\pi$. The argument in my previous comment implies you must be wrong, so to find your error you should try writing out the integral in detail. Notice your parametrization will now be $(1+0.04\cos t, 0.04\sin t)$. And notice the cancellation that happens...

Comment: Last question: the domain of where the function $U$ is the potential function to the field is all of $xy$ except for $(1,0)$?

Comment: @Yos: the function $U=\arctan(\frac{y}{x-1})$ isn't defined when $x=1$. The domain in which $U$ is a potential for $(P, Q)$ is disconnected by the line $x=1$.

Comment: The function $U = \arctan(\frac{y}{x-1})$ can be extended to a function defined everywhere except on a "branch cut" such as $x \le 1, y = 0$.  (See, for example, the C function `atan2` which is a typical example of this.)  In fact, that gives another way to calculate the integral: by taking out a small piece of the ellipse near the branch cut, on which piece the integral is tiny, the rest of the integral then becomes the difference in $U$ between the two sides of the branch cut, which is exactly $2 \pi$.

Comment: What would be the curve to calculate the potential, the ellipse curve? But it's parametrization, provided I did it correctly, is $c(t)=\langle 5\cos t,6\sin t\rangle$ and if we calculate it from $0$ to $2\pi$ then $5\cos t=0, 6\sin t=0$ which doesn't make sense

Comment: @Yos: I don't know what your last comment means. Are you asking how someone figured out that $U(x,y)=\arctan(\frac{y}{x-1})$ is a potential function for $(P,Q)$ (in the region where it's defined)? That has nothing to do with the ellipse. To find a potential $U$, you want $U_x=P$ and $U_y=Q$. So integrate $P$ with respect to $x$; that gives $U=\arctan(\frac{y}{x-1})+C(y)$, where $C(y)$ is some function of $y$ alone. Differentiating this $U$ with respect to $y$ and setting it equal to $Q$ shows we can take $C(y)=0$.

Comment: The way I understood Daniel Schepter's comment is that we can also calculate the integral with the potenial function. But for that we need two points for $x$ and $y$. How do I get those two points?