# Solving a curve integral $\int_\phi \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

We have the following curve integral:

$\int_\phi \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$

Where the curve $\phi$ is the curve around the following area, in positive direction:

[image]

We do not know the equation of the curve and we do not know which points it goes through. How do you solve this?

Comment: See the second half of my answer to the following question for a detailed description of how to compute line integrals of curl-free fields around curves that contain singularities: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394500/how-to-calculate-line-integral-over-an-ellipse-with-vector-field-undefined-insid

Comment: Thank you! That write up was good and I understand this problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve defined by $\phi$ is clearly diffeomorphic to the unit circle of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the differential form $\frac{x\mathrm{d}y-y\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+y^2}$ is the angle-form on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$, hence the desired integral is equal to $2\pi$.

Comment: This answer, though right and concise, is almost surely beyond the level of the OP.